# How to properly document keys of array return type?

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

```
class Foo
{
    /**
    *   
    * @return array
    */
    public funtion bar(): array
    {
        return [
            'x' => 1,
            'y' => 2        
        ];
    }
}
```

How do you properly tell in the documentation that `bar()` returns an `array` with `x` and `y` as keys?

Comment: Maybe `int[]` is what u are looking for? *

Comment: @NikolaGavric ehm, it's not even string, it is `int[]`

Comment: Ye, type, thanks, but anyway, you can't specify the `names` you are going to return, only the types, which in this case is an array of strings

Comment: [Not currently possible.](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/650) You can specify it as text within the comment block, but there is no specific syntax for it at the moment. You can specify the value types of simple values though, as was mentioned above, using `type[]`.

Comment: `int[]` followed by a textual explanation is as close as you can currently get. If it's important, you can also consider switching to objects, so you can do e.g. `@return Point`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not supported yet on PHP Doc (and I doubt that it will be in the future)...

Anyway you can write your array structure in the description part of @return:

```
/**
 * @return mixed[] Description, structured as:
 *                [
 *                   'x' => int
 *                   'y' => string
 *                ];
 */
```